# Compression and Decompression of ECG Signal using HUFFMAN ALGORITHM

Tags: matlab, compression, huffman-code

I want to compress and decompress a ecg signal stored as text message a text file and find out the file size, cr,prd ratio,and qs.

Here is my code for compression and decompression of ecg signal using huffman algorithm. I'm trying to find out the file size, compression ratio,prd ratio,qs.

But this is the error I'm getting

> the ecg file initially is in text format.

```
        %clearing all variables and screen

        enter code here

        clear all;

        close all;

        clc;

        [file1]=uigetfile('*.txt');

        %fprintf('Enter the ECG file name :%s',file1);

        p=file1;

        t=sprintf('%s',p);

        b1=dlmread([file1]);

        len=length(b1);

        lead=input('Enter lead Number :');

        %lead=str2double(lead);  

        col2=b1(1:end,lead);

        e=fix(sqrt(len));
        m=1;

         for i=1:e

         for j=1:e

         g2(i,j)=fix(col2(m)*1000); %Amplifying by 1000

         m=m+1;

         end

         end

         g3=g2;


         for i=1:e

         for j=1:e


         if(g3(i,j)<0)


          g3(i,j)=(g3(i,j))*(-1);

          end

          end

          end

          max_term=g3(1,1);


           for i=1:e


           for j=1:e

           if(g3(i,j)>max_term)

          max_term=g3(i,j);

          end

          end

          end


         time=b1(1:end,1)*1000;



         plot(time,col2);


         xlabel('Time / s'); ylabel('Voltage / mV');


         string=['INPUT ECG SIGNAL :: ',t];



         title(string);


         %title('Input ECG Signal:t');


         grid on;





        %%%%%%%%%%%INPUT FILE %%%%%%%%%%%%%

         fid=fopen('inputfile.txt','w+');


         cnt2=fwrite(fid,col2);


         fclose(fid);


         %%%%%%A%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 



         a=g3;


         I=a;



        [m,n]=size(I);


        Totalcount=m*n;

         %variables using to find the probability

         cnt=1;




         sigma=0;



         %computing the cumulative probability.


         for i=0:max_term

         k=I==i;

         count(cnt)=sum(k(:))


         %pro array is having the probabilities


         pro(cnt)=count(cnt)/Totalcount;


         sigma=sigma+pro(cnt);


         cumpro(cnt)=sigma;

         cnt=cnt+1;

         end;

        %Symbols for the signal

        symbols = [0:max_term];


        %Huffman code Dictionary

        dict = huffmandict(symbols,pro);

           %function which converts array to vector

         vec_size = 1;

          for p = 1:m

          for q = 1:n

         newvec(vec_size) = I(p,q);

         vec_size = vec_size+1;

         end

         end

          %Huffman Encodig

           hcode = huffmanenco(newvec,dict);

           %Huffman Decoding

           dhsig1 = huffmandeco(hcode,dict);

           %convertign dhsig1 double to dhsig uint8

           dhsig = uint8(dhsig1);


           %vector to array conversion

            dec_row=sqrt(length(dhsig));



            dec_col=dec_row;

            %variables using to convert vector 2 array

            arr_row = 1;

            arr_col = 1;

            vec_si = 1;

              for x = 1:m

              for y = 1:n

             back(x,y)=dhsig(vec_si);

             arr_col = arr_col+1;

             vec_si = vec_si + 1;

             end

             arr_row = arr_row+1;

             end

             z=b1(1:end,1)*750;

             %converting  grayscale to rgb

             [deco, map] = gray2ind(back,256);

             RGB = ind2rgb(deco,map);


             figure,subplot(1,2,1),title('original graph'),...

             subplot(1,2,1),plot(b1,col2),xlabel('Time / s');   

             figure,subplot(1,2,1),plot(time,col2),xlabel('Time / s');        

             ylabel('Voltage / mV'),grid on,title('Decompressed graph');

             % subplot(2,2,3),imshow((b1)),title('compressed graph');



             % K=imfinfo('original.jpg');

             % size_of_file=K.FileSize

             %K=imfinfo('compressed.jpg');

             %size_of_file=K.FileSize


             %K=imfinfo('fdr.jpg');

             %size_of_file=K.FileSize

             disp('Size of original ECG in bytes'); 


             disp(bytes(p));

             disp('Size of ECG after Compression'); 


             fid=fopen('comp1.txt','w+'); % compressed file "comp.dat"


             cnt=fwrite(fid,q);

             fclose(fid);

             disp(bytes('comp1.txt'));



             disp('Size of DECOMPRESSED ECG'); 

             fid=fopen('recons1.txt','w+');

             cnt1=fwrite(fid,pro);


             fclose(fid);

             disp(bytes(pro));


             %  disp('Size of ECG after RE-construct in bytes'); 
             %  fid=fopen('recons1.dat','w+');
             %  cnt1=fwrite(fid,g13);
             %  fclose(fid);
             %  disp(bytes('recons1.dat'));



           %%%%%%% PRD Calculation %%%%%%%%%%%%%
             e=length(p);

              for i=1:e

              y3(i)=ecg(i)- main_t(i);

              y4(i)=(y3(i).^2);


       %      y5=sum(y4(i));

              y5(i)=(ecg(i).^2);
               end
              y6=sum(y4)/sum(y5);


              prd=sqrt(y6);

              disp('AFTER calculation PRD:');

              disp(prd);


              b0=bytes(p);



              b1=bytes('comp1.txt');

              CR1=b0/b1;

              CR=100/CR1;

              disp('AFTER calculation CR%:');

              disp(CR);

              disp('QUALITY SCORE');

               c=double(CR);

               d=double(prd);


                qs=double(c/(d*100));

                 disp(qs);


                %end of the huffman coding
```

Errors:
My code is half executing and then is giving an error  in line no 189 in finding out the size after compression  specifically the error is in this line : 
cnt=fwrite(fid,q);

Comment: Please tell us what error do you receive and try to reduce the posted code by posting only the portions relevant to the error.

Comment: Please, indent that code!!!!!! Go to Matlab: CTRL+A CTRL+I.

Comment: Which line does the error occur in?

Answer (score 0):

The code is strangely executable if you avoid for a moment some lines

```
line#23    %g3=g2(i,j);
line#31    %max_term=g3(1,1);
```

but it would be helpful if you share some more precise information about the problem and ecg file to load. I mean ecg data format.